# Copy multiple directories to another multiple directories from Linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, cp

I want to copy several directories to another directories. How do I do it from the shell command prompt? for example:

```
Project
├── directory1
│   └── files1
├── directory2
│   └── files2
└── directory3
    └── files3
```

to :

```
Project
├── directory1
│   └── files1
├── directory2
│   └── files2
├── directory3
│   └── files3
├── directory1.copy
│   └── files1
├── directory2.copy
│   └── files2
└── directory3.copy
    └── files3
```

tried this:

```
mkdir directory{1..3}.copy 
cp -r directory{1..3} directory{1..3}.copy
```

but all directories (and files inside) copy in directory3.copy

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `cp` just accepts all arguments before the first as sources and the last one as destination. If you want to copy to multiple places, you need a loop.

```
for dir in ./*/.  # or for dir in directory{1..3}
do
    cp -r "$dir" "$dir.copy"
done
```